# Oracle drop constraint unique and re-add it

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I've drop a constraint unique key with command:

```
ALTER TABLE table
    DROP CONSTRAINT UNIQUE uk_nome;
```

it's removed because I don't see it, but when I try to re-add it with different parameter:

```
ALTER TABLE tale ADD CONSTRAINT UK_name UNIQUE (uk_1, uk_2);
```

I receive the error:

> Errore SQL: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You drop `uk_nome` and then add `uk_name`. I mean that there is a typo in  `uk_nome`.

Comment: is not possible because the uk_name is deleted and there was only 1 record, with sqldeveloper I don't see unique key record

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**, the unique key is present, like index, into the system in the table dba_objects

Comment: So you never dropped it? Was then because the typo?